# WordPress theme preview-er? Where to start?

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress, iframe

I am looking to implement a "theme preview" of a WordPress theme I developed, like the ones you see on Themeforest where it basically wraps your website or WP theme in a frame and allows you to change the viewport to various device sizes to showcase the responsiveness. Example link below.

[SAMPLE LINK](http://themes.array.is/browse/?theme=editor)

Where does one even start? I have looked for hours on Google to find a clue where to start... nothing!

Is it really just about wrapping the website in an Iframe and using JS to control the size of the iframe?  I feel like there would be a cleaner, lighter solution out there somewhere.

I would like to build this myself or find an open source plug-in.  I know there are pay versions out there but looking to gather opinions and find a clear solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for all the responses everyone but I managed to take my own advice and was able to work something out. Maybe someone out there will find this handy one day but here was my solution using Jquery. And yes, all I did was create a blank page with a header and iframe.

I assigned unique ID's to my "a" tags as identifiers for the jquery:

```
<ul>
  <li class="icon-row"><a id="viewport-change-desktop" href="#"><img src="img/desktop-icon@2x.png" height="48px" width="60px" alt="Desktop Viewport" /></a></li>
  <li class="icon-row"><a id="viewport-change-laptop" href="#"><img src="img/laptop-icon@2x.png" height="30px" width="47px" alt="Laptop Viewport" /></a></li>
  <li class="icon-row"><a id="viewport-change-tablet" href="#"><img src="img/tablet-icon@2x.png" height="25" width="18" alt="Tablet Viewport" /></a></li>
  <li class="icon-row"><a id="viewport-change-mobile" href="#"><img src="img/mobile-icon@2x.png" height="20px" width="9px" alt="Mobile Viewport" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

The CSS here is irrelevant to solving the problem, only the "a id=". Using the unique ID's in my HTML, I was able to craft some jquery like this:

```
$( "#viewport-change-desktop" ).click(function () {
  $("iframe").width('100%');
  $("iframe").height('100%');
});
$( "#viewport-change-laptop" ).click(function () {
  $("iframe").width(1024);
  $("iframe").height(768);
});
$( "#viewport-change-tablet" ).click(function () {
  $("iframe").width(768);
  $("iframe").height(800);
});
$( "#viewport-change-mobile" ).click(function () {
  $("iframe").width(320);
  $("iframe").height(568);
});
```

Now my icons in my header bar I created will resize the iframe containing the WordPress theme on click to values I was able to set. Therefore, answering my own question.  Rock on!

[**FULL TUTORIAL HERE**](http://benkaminski.com/2014/11/30/responsive-websitetheme-preview-tutorial-showcase-your-websites-responsiveness-to-the-end-user/)

Comment: Hi Ben, I came across your question AND answer last week and tried it myself. I made some modifications but the idea is still the same. Hope you wouldn't mind me sharing it here. http://dokgu.com/product/acros/

Comment: Dokgu... I don't mind at all! Thanks for sharing, site looks good and it's great that you're offering it for free! Thanks Dokgu.